# How to insert weekdays names in sql column based on given date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to know how to insert weekday names in a column in sql server based on the current date. I want to insert the days until current day. For example, I want something as per the following column for today (2014-12-04),

```
day_of_week
-----------
Monday 
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
```

On next Tuesday(2014-12-09), I want to display,

```
day_of_week
-----------
Monday
Tuesday
```

Let me know how can I do this in sql server 2012?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can also be done using a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS
(   
   SELECT DATENAME(weekday,getdate()) AS NameOfDay, 
          DAY(getdate()) AS NumberOfDay,
          getdate() AS curDate                   

   UNION ALL

   SELECT DATENAME(weekday,DATEADD(day, -1, curDate)) As NameOfDay, 
          DAY(DATEADD(day, -1, curDate)) AS NumberOfDay,
          DATEADD(day, -1, curDate) AS curDate
   FROM cte
   WHERE DAY(GETDATE()) - DAY(DATEADD(day, -1, curDate)) >= 0
)
SELECT NameOfDay
FROM cte  
ORDER BY NumberOfDay
```

Comment: Thats a nice solution too! Execution plan says this query costs is higher tho.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
select datename(weekday,n) 
from (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) wdays(n)
where n < datepart(weekday,'20141209') - 1
```

And if you're not using sql 2008 and up you can do

```
select datename(weekday,n) 
from (select 0
union all
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select 3
union all
select 4
union all
select 5
union all
select 6
) wdays(n)
where n < datepart(weekday,'20141209') - 1
```

Comment: Nice approach -- a couple slight changes though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41408

Comment: Are you sure you are on a sql server 2008? I edited so it can be used in lower versions too...

Comment: I am sorry. It is SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Hatsjoem If you execute your first query with '20141207' it returns no rows The same holds for the second query as well.

Comment: Strange, it does with me... have you tried with `getdate()`?

Comment: @Hatsjoem '20141207' is a Sunday. I get no rows for this value when i simply cut and paste your queries in SSMS. I don't know, could I be doing sth wrong?

Comment: Seems like some settings 2014-12-07 is december the 7th for me and the 12th of june for you...

Comment: I changed my system date to 7th of December 2014, then used GETDATE() in your query. I still get no rows. Note that with current date set to 7th of December 2014, this 'select datepart(weekday, getdate())' gives me 1 as result (?)